# Normalizing non-ASCII unicode digits and alphabets in javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, character-encoding, character

I am processing some user input. Some of them use non-ASCII digits and alphabets characters (e.g. ④❹), and I want to convert them to regular characters (a-zA-Z0-9).

I found that google search and google chrome can hit these by regular characters.
[image]

Is there any package, prebuilt table or algorithm to replace such non-ASCII characters into the regular one without listing all of them by myself?

Edit: I have found [string.normalize("NFKD")](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) but it seems not working for some cases (see snippet below).

```js
console.log("④❹ ".normalize("NFKD"))
```

Comment: It depends on the scope. You may want to compatibility normalize your string (recommended for searches). You may want to check also the numeric value (if available for such character). But then you still have similar looking characters, and there are just some tables (not very official/maintained) about confusable parameters.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I would like to care about exact one to one characters replacement (e.g.  to A), and not similar looking characters (e.g. not 0 to O).

Comment: I have just found a built in function string.normalize("NFKD").
It works for most cases but some not (e.g.  and ❹ in the question's example).

Comment: Similar looking are e.g. A (which can be Latin, Greek, Cyrillic). But normalization (K) will handle most of your cases. -- See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize , with "NFKC"